# django filter get filter field value inside the view

Tags: django, django-filter

I have my filter like this

```
class SummaryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
start = django_filters.DateFilter(
    field_name="date_modified",
    lookup_expr="gte",
)
end = django_filters.DateFilter(
    field_name="date_modified",
    lookup_expr="lte",
)
```

and in my view i am doing like this

```
class GetRiskyUsersSummary(generics.ListAPIView):
   model = Summary
   queryset = Summary.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.ModelSerializer
   filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
   filterset_class = SummaryFilter

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    response = {}
    ********doing some stuff here and return in response*******
    **** for doing these i need the cleaned start and end date as date objects like below but couldnt figure out the option for this in the library****
    self.filter.cleaned_data.get('start')
    self.filter.cleaned_data.get('end')
    
    return Response({"response": response})
```

How can I get this data in the view ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"cleaned start and end date"*? the data from query parameter?

Comment: by cleaned i meant the data after form validate. So in request.GET i will have the date as a string, after cleaned i will get the date object.

Comment: afaik, you can't do that. But, you can parse it yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the filter data by initializing it

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    myfilter = self.filterset_class(request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    if myfilter.is_valid():
        queryset = myfilter.qs
        myfilter.form.cleaned_data.get('start')
        myfilter.form.cleaned_data.get('end')
```